# Getting Values from textbox to another textbox within same jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

is it possible that the value I inserted to one textbox will be inserted to another textbox within same jsp without clicking the submit button?

Example I have textbox1 and I type 123, on the textbox3 123 will also be typed. It just like getting value of the textbox1 and textbox3 will copy the value of textbox1.

JSP FILE:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Profile</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/reset/reset.css">


</head>

<body>


<form method="POST" action='Controller' name="add" id="msform" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure to update the data?')">

        <fieldset>
        <div class="field--wrapper">
        <label for ="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="texbox1" value="<c:out value="${person.firstname}" />" />
        </div>


        <div class="field--wrapper">
        <p>Gender</p>
        </div>

        <div class="field--wrapper">
        <select name="select1">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="Male" <c:if test = "${person.gender == 'Male'}">selected</c:if>>Male</option>
        <option value="Female" <c:if test = "${[person.gender == 'Female'}">selected</c:if>>Female</option>
        </select>
        </div>



        <div class="field--wrapper">
        <label for ="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="textbox2" value="<c:out value="${person.address}" />" />
        </div>  


        <!-- The Value above will be reflected to the value below -->

        <fieldset>
        <div class="field--wrapper">
        <label for ="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="texbox3" />
        </div>


        <div class="field--wrapper">
        <p>Gender</p>
        </div>

        <div class="field--wrapper">
        <select name="select2">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="Male" >Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
        </div>



        <div class="field--wrapper">
        <label for ="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="texbox4"/>
        </div>  

        <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="submit" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using `jsp` objects , rather could be done with `jquery` ,

```
$("#text_1").keyup(function() {
    $("#text_3").val($("#text_1").val());
})
```

An working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/San_Krish/robLw04n/) here.

Comment: Are you sure that the OP is allowed or able to use Jquery?

Comment: But OP didnt mention that he wants it to be done with plain vannila js alone . rather want it to be done on his jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Without any extra page reload, you only can achive it with Javascript. Here comes a possible way:

Add to field "textbox1" the attribut `onKeyUp()`:

```
<input type="text" name="texbox1" 
  value="<c:out value="${person.firstname}" />"
  onKeyup="copyValue(this)" />
```

Write the Javascript function:

```
function copyValue(formfield) {
  document.add.textbox3.value = formfield.value;
}
```

**Based on the OP's further question here a full working example.**

The javascript:

```
 <script>
  function copyValue(formfield)
  {
   switch (formfield.name) {
    case "texbox1":
     document.add.texbox3.value = formfield.value;
     break;
    case "textbox2":
     document.add.texbox4.value = formfield.value;
     break;
    case "select1":
     for (optItemIndex = 0; optItemIndex < document.add.select2.length; optItemIndex++)
     {
      if (document.add.select2.options[optItemIndex].value == formfield.value) 
         {document.add.select2.options[optItemIndex].selected = true;}
     }
     break;
   }
  }
 </script>
```

**The HTML source code:**

```
    <form method="POST" action='Controller' name="add" id="msform"
 onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure to update the data?')">
     <fieldset>
      <div class="field--wrapper">
       <label for ="firstname">Firstname</label>
       <input type="text" name="texbox1" value="" onKeyUp="copyValue(this)"/>
      </div>
      <div class="field--wrapper">
       <p>Gender</p>
      </div>
      <div class="field--wrapper">
       <select name="select1" onChange="copyValue(this)">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
       </select>
      </div>
      <div class="field--wrapper">
       <label for ="address">Address</label>
       <input type="text" name="textbox2" value="" onKeyUp="copyValue(this)"/>
      </div>  
      <!-- The Value above will be reflected to the value below -->
      <fieldset>
       <div class="field--wrapper">
        <label for ="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="texbox3" />
       </div>
      <div class="field--wrapper">
       <p>Gender</p>
      </div>
      <div class="field--wrapper">
       <select name="select2">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="Male" >Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
       </select>
      </div>
      <div class="field--wrapper">
       <label for ="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="texbox4"/>
      </div>  
      <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
     </fieldset>    
</form>
```

Hopefully it will meet the requirements and answers some questions.

Comment: Is this right? I tried using this but it doesn't work.


      
`<script type="text/javascript">
function copyValue(formfield) {
   documents.add.textbox3.value = formfield.value;
 }</script>

<input type="text" name="textbox1" 
 onKeyup="copyValue(this)" />
<input type="text" name="textbox3" />`

Comment: There was a small mistake in my answer. The letter 's' was/is invalid at `document`.

Comment: A made a example for you, based on your code. My answer has being updated.